# How would i archive to show 3 different articles in single page with Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have Section  caled SECT_X and in in the that section, 32 different categories.

Each of these categories are in the menu and each menu entry should show a single page with a templaet that has 3 columns.

Each of the columns should contain different article or a block of text that is unique to its section.

Example data:

```
SECT_X ->
  CAT_1 -> 
    INTRO_1
    HISTORY_1
    FUTURE_1
  CAT_2 -> 
    INTRO_2
    HISTORY_2
    FUTURE_"
  CAT_3 -> 
    INTRO_3
    HISTORY_3
    FUTURE_3
```

Any ideas on how to implement this ? Menu part is straight forward, i c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real solution but got it:

Copied all the catogories to sections and made intro, history & future as categories  and with content include module i can fetch the all the articles in section and place them on any of the columns.